# Git: How to squash into a new branch

Tags: git, branch, squash

My team wants me to squash, but sometimes they want me to split it again (per certain aspects).

After squash (`git rebase -i`), the branch moves and the old commits are left in "vacuum".
I would like to leave the branch on the old unsquashed commits, to be able to return to it easily.

Is there a single command way to leave the old branch position named somehow, or the other way around, create a new branch for the squashed commits?

Comment: Just create a new branch or tag before starting to rebase. Actually the old commits are not in "vacuum", you can find them using `git reflog`.

Comment: Is the branch you have in mind a local branch on your machine or a public branch on a remote?  Rhenus' solution would seem to work provided you haven't made additional commits past the head where you did the squash.